# “International themed” or “internationally themed”?

Tags: word-usage, adverbials

Would you say “an international themed party” or “an internationally themed party”?

Comment: It depends on what you are calling "international." If the party is international, then the adjective "international" modifies the noun *party*, and it is "an international, themed party" but we don't know what the specific theme is. If the *theme* is international, then it is "an internationally themed party" so that the adverb "internationally" modifies the adjective "themed."

Comment: I liked my comment enough to make it an answer.

Comment: Sorry, “internal” was supposed to be “international.” Just changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you are calling "international."

If the *party* is international, then the adjective "international" modifies the noun party, and it is "an international, themed party" but we don't know what the specific theme is.

If the *theme* is international, then it is "an internationally themed party" so that the adverb "internationally" modifies the adjective "themed."